# How to mock properties with jest.fn()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

I have the following code:

```js
this.$vs.loading()
....
this.$vs.loading.close()
```

I need to pass a mock to shallowMount like this:

```js
const vs = {
  loading: jest.fn()
}

mocks: {
   $vs: vs
}
```

But how can I mock `loading` and `close`?

Using `loading: jest.fn()`, I just mock `loading()`. How do I mock `close()` inside the `loading` property?

Answer (score 5):

You can attach the mocked property to the mock function itself:

```js
const vs = {
  loading: jest.fn()
}
vs.loading.close = jest.fn()
```